# How to correctly interpret index usages from EXPLAIN of mysql?

Tags: mysql, index, explain

[image]

I've exported the results of an EXPLAIN run on a query. What I find confusing is that there's the key column listing out one of the indexes from the list of **possible_keys**(not shown in picture) however only the top row makes mention of **Using index** explicitely in the **Extra** column.

1. What does this mean in the 2nd row, is it not using the index listed
   in the key column?
2. How should I interpret what the contents of the
   key column is about and how it is used?
   enter code here

   a. Should I interpret this as
   that index is used in the where stage of this query?

Comment: It would be helpful to post the complete plan, along with the actual query and table definitions, because "using index" might mean different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

`Using index` means that the columns used for that table are *all* in the chosen index.  This is called a "covering index".

Note the terminology confusion:  the `Key` column tells you whether it is "using an index"; `Using index` says whether that index is "covering" in this usage.

`Using index condition` is something else; don't get confused.

`Using temporary; Using filesort` does not necessarily apply to the table in question.  See `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for specifically which `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY` are creating a temp table and/or sorting.

`ref=const` probably means something like:  `INDEX(foo)` with `WHERE foo=123`.  `key_len=8` *usually* refers to a `BIGINT NOT NULL`.

`ref=Production1_` may be a truncation of `Production1_db.my_table.my_column`

The second row does not say `Using index` because the index being used in the second table (FKB8...) is not "covering".

`EXPLAIN` mostly ignores `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT`.  Instead, it focuses on what index(es), if any, is used for `WHERE` or `ON`.